# PHP: How to sort a multidimensional array based on searched terms

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alfresco, cmis

Is it possible to sort multidimensional array keys by searched terms? For example, i have something like this:

```
 $list =   array(
      'search' => array(
        'name' => 'Jon'),
      'search else' => array(
        'name' => 'Matt'),
      'not this' => array(
        'name' => 'Dan'),
      'neither this' => array(
        'name' => 'Oz'),
      'always search me' => array(
        'name' => 'Lukas')
    );

function sort_by_search($x, $y) {
  $term = $_GET['keyword'];
    return $x[$term] == $y[$term];
}

uasort($list, 'sort_by_search');

print_r($list);
```

Now if i pass the keyword term 'search' in the url, how can i return the array so that all the keys that contain the word 'search' are rendered on top?

It needs to come back like:

```
Array
(
    [search] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jon
        )

    [search else] => Array
        (
            [name] => Matt
        )

    [always search me] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lukas
        )

    [not this] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dan
        )

    [neither this] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oz
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

 $list =   array(
      'search' => array(
        'name' => 'Jon'),
      'search else' => array(
        'name' => 'Matt'),
      'not this' => array(
        'name' => 'Dan'),
      'neither this' => array(
        'name' => 'Oz'),
      'always search me' => array(
        'name' => 'Lukas')
    );

function key_compare($a, $b)
{
    $test_a = stripos($a, 'search');
    $result_a = (false===$test_a)?1:0;

    $test_b = stripos($b, 'search');
    $result_b = (false===$test_b)?1:0;

    return $result_a-$result_b;
}

uksort($list, 'key_compare');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [search] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jon
        )

    [search else] => Array
        (
            [name] => Matt
        )

    [always search me] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lukas
        )

    [not this] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dan
        )

    [neither this] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oz
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works wonderfully. Learned something new today. I want to +1 your answer but i just joined the site and have not established a reputation yet.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to look up the documentation on uksort, just to see what it does exactly and how it might help you in the future. When time permits, I'll expand on my answer to give a little more background information.